# Applying DDD on the following recruitment system

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an issue applying DDD most of the examples found online are either too complex or too simple ( Item/ItemOrder type)

I have a Recruitment System,
A Department may have a number of Professions ( A Profession cannot exist without a department)
A Recruitment Channel may have a number of Recruitment Sources ( A Recruitment source cannot exist without a Recruitment Channel )
Now I have an Applicant that cannot exist without a Profession and cannot exist without a Recruitment source.
Also an Interview cannot exist if there is no Candidate ( however I see the Interview part within another bounded context like Interview Calendar messaged through domainevents)

I am trying to understand how to extract what is what in terms of DDD AggregateRoot etc. (here I believe I have two competing parties Department and Recruitment Channel)
Given I choose one over the other, how would I handle the other?

Maybe I am going about it the wrong way. If anyone can illuminate me it would be very helpful.

Comment: You are trying to apply DDD concepts to a bunch of objects simply connected by some constraints.  That is not a useful domain model.

Comment: I did that because it is as explained in domain-driven-design-fundamentals pluralsight she says that is how you will know that an entity has to be part of an aggregate "it cannot exist without".

Answer (score 4):

> Maybe I am going about it the wrong way. If anyone can illuminate me it would be very helpful.

Step #1: look to the ubiquitous language.  Sit down with your domain experts, and pay really careful attention to the entities that they talk about.

For example:

> Applicant that cannot exist without a Profession and cannot exist without a Recruitment source.

That seems a bit weird.  I'd expect an applicant to be a person, and people certainly exist without a "recruitment source" (whatever that is).  If you were to say that an Application can't exist without a Recruitment source, or even better that Applications are always referred by Recruitment sources, I'm more likely to believe that you are actually talking to experts in the domain.

Domain models don't describe structure; domain models *control change*.

You can't make intelligent design decisions about aggregates until you understand the changes that are permitted by the model.  Or better said, which changes are 
*not* permitted.

Identifying entities is a part of the modeling effort, but you really need to pay careful attention to which entities are subordinate to the model.  For instance, consider Customer vs Account; the model probably doesn't control the customer (can your model prevent the human being from changing their name? or moving?), but it may be able to control the account (suspend, track promotional offers, promote to VIP status).

Heuristic: if your business doesn't control it, then your model doesn't control it either.

Answer (score 2):

Seems, that you don't `ask right questions` to your domain experts.
All the information you got here is what can / can't exists with something else.
Do you know `what does` profession, department, interview in the context of the system?
Your requirements are all about data (tables relations), not the `behaviour` itself.

In `DDD`, you put `verbs` over nouns. And you catch them as your aggregate methods. Then you choose the aggregate boundaries depending on the transaction boundaries (Does it need to happen with this, or may it wait?).

- First ask your domain experts about about `requirements` of the system. What functions should it provide.
- Then ask about `user stories`, which are just simple usages of the system.   But `don't talk about the front`! 
  This is `not user story` - *When user click buy button and submit the form, then he buys a product*
  This may be your `user story` - *As a user when I buy car and I am a VIP I should receive 20% discount so I will make another buy soon*

From user stories you may extract some useful information, which are more than for example: "shop can have multiple products, but product can have one title." 
I hope you get a point.

About how to model aggregates, take a look here [Vaughn Vernon](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838)